# Add Bias to classification after training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cross-entropy

I have a dataset with classes [a, b] where during training I have made sure that the dataset is equally balanced. I have trained the network using cross-entropy loss with equal importance.

I am able to achieve an accuracy of around 90% for both classes a and b. However in reality I would prefer to network to have much higher accuracy for class a with an allowed decrease of accuracy for class b.

I have managed to somewhat solve this in the following way:

1. Split data into train/validtion/test data.
2. Train network on train data and end at maximum validation accuracy.
3. As a post proccess step. Change so that the binary output of the network is not taken as argmax of the output but instead a modified argmax requiring an output value larger than 0.5 for b to classify as b instead of a.
4. Use test dataset to verify that the result is as expected.

With this I can reach an example result of the following: Before modifying argmax function:

- Train accuracy {a : 0.95, b : 0.95}
- Validation accuracy {a : 0.90, b : 0.90}
- Test accuracy {a : 0.90, b : 0.90}

After modifying argmax function until 0.99 accuracy for a:

- Validation accuracy {a : 0.99, b : 0.80}
- Test accuracy {a : 0.98, b : 0.78}

This is fine for my application but is there a more scientific and "correct" way to achieve this result? I am using pytorch to train the model.

Comment: Why not just classify everything as that once class of interest? (If this is an unacceptable way to proceed, please say why, as that will say a lot about how you value the various kinds of mistakes.)

Comment: You may find these threads interesting: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)
and [Is accuracy an improper scoring rule in a binary classification setting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352)
I would recommend you separate the probabilistic classification step from a threshold-based decision step: [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352) [This Meta.CV thread contains useful links on imbalanced data.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/1352)

Comment: @Dave in this example with A and B. The entire reason for training the model is to find instances of B. But I will have an infinite number of samples to test and it is not too important if I miss a few of them. It however becomes an issue if half of the B classifications are false. When using the network about 99% of the samples will be if A. So if I have 90% accuracy in both classes. 9/10 or so of the use case B classifications will be wrong. TLDR: I’m interested in B but have infinite samples and can not have to many A classified as B

Comment: @StephanKolassa thank you I will have a look at those

Comment: @Dave I have forgotten a lot since I read about statistic but I think what I am saying is: The main objective is a high precision of B, not a high recall